# How to wake up MainActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, wakelock, power-management

My app has 3 activities; MainActivity has a large ImgeView with a jpg picture in main layout.

Activities are changed with this code:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    startActivityForResult(i,70);// arbitrary
```

and back to MainActivity with code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 70: // do something on return
```

My problem is that during the time spent in activity1, MainActivity goes to sleep (not sure if the right word) and the picture is dimmed and looking wrong.

android:keepScreenOn="true" in layout does not work
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);  // not working

I have added in manifest:
"android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"

How to keep the image bright?

[image: Not dimmed]

[image: dimmed]

Comment: Its very strange. Can you provide the screnshot of your "sleeping" activity?

Comment: How do I attach pictures?